# hide a div when entered value in input field is deleted in angular

Tags: angular, onchange

I am populating book title after entering book number and clicking outside the field . It is working fine but when the user deletes the already entered value i want to hide that div, on change function doesn't seem to work. And also search button will be enabled only if both input field has value and title is displayed. Can someone help me .

**component:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  searchMoviesCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredMovies: any;
  isLoading = false;
  errorMsg: string;
  title:string;
  showFlag:boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getBookDetail(){
 
    this.title ="Harry Poter";
    this.showFlag = true;

  }
}
```

**html**

```
<div>
    <form>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="BookNumber" #bookNumber (focusout)=getBookDetail()>
      </mat-form-field>
  
    <div *ngIf= showFlag> book {{title}}</div>
</form>
  
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled] = "!bookNumber.value || !showFlag">Search Book</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there's two ways to achieve your purpose. The two distincts DOM renderings, choose what actually fits your demand.

1. Hide your div (`visibility: hidden` CSS attribute) but keep the `div` rendered in the HTML page flow.

**component.ts**

```
showFlag = true;
```

**component.html**

```
<div [style.visibility]="!showFlag ? 'hidden' : 'visible'"> book {{title}}</div>
```

2. Remove your div (`display: none` CSS attribute) and remove it from your HTML page flow.

**component.ts**

```
showFlag = true;
```

**component.html**

```
<div [style.display]="!showFlag ? 'none' : 'block'"> book {{title}}</div>
```

Enabling and disabling your button:

**component.ts**

```
disableSubmitButton = true;
bookNumber: string;

checkSubmitButton() {
  if (this.bookNumber.toString().length > 0 && showFlag === false) {
    this.disableSubmitButton = false;
  } else {
    this.disableSubmitButton = true;
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<input matInput placeholder="BookNumber" #bookNumber (focusout)=getBookDetail() [(ngModel)]="buttonNumber" 
(ngModelChange)="checkSubmitButton()">

<button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="disableSubmitButton">Search Book</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your app.component.ts to:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  filteredMovies: any;
  isLoading = false;
  errorMsg: string;
  title: string = 'Harry Potter';
  bookForm = this.fb.group({bookNumber: ['', Validators.required]})
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

}
```

The above uses reactive forms which is a much more elegant way to manage the status of your forms. You can set multiple validators, and default values.

In your html use:

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="bookForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="BookNumber" formControlName="bookNumber">
      </mat-form-field>
    <div *ngIf="bookForm.get('bookNumber')?.value"> book {{title}}</div>
</form>
  
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled] = "bookForm.invalid">Search Book</button>
  </div>
```

Dont forget to import **FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule** into your app.module.ts. If youre on an older version of angular/ts switch your *ngIf on the div to

```
bookForm.get('bookNumber') && bookForm.get('bookNumber').value
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Ideally i  want to get book title after coming out the field as i would change the function to get it from service . so on every key press service call would happen which is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

The `*ngIf` needs quotations to work, that might fix your problem.

`*ngIf="bookNumber.value"` should only display the div if you have input in the bookNumber input.